# why python error in call to class...cannot "see" the function

Tags: python-2.7

Sorry for asking a simple question...but I've spent almost an hour trying to figure out what is wrong.  I'm not a super-experienced python person but have written maybe 1000 lines of code since beginning a few months ago in school.

I've dumbed it down to this..

"calling" .py pgm:

```
import wclass1
passingString = "this is test"
wclass1.wfunction1(passingString)
```

"called" class wclass1.py pgm:

```
class wclass1():
#        
    def wfunction1(receivedString):
        print(receivedString)
        return
```

error message from py2.7 under win10/Spyder:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'wfunction1'

I'm sure it must be something simple.  Can someone get me over this hump please?  Thanks.....

Comment: I've removed some code like __init__ and self from the class to dumb it down, but maybe I removed too much.  I'm trying to write a class with functions inside.

Answer (score 0):

calling.py

```
from wclass1 import wclass1
passingString = "this is test"
wclass1().wfunction1(passingString)
```

wclass1.py

```
class wclass1():
#        
    def wfunction1(self, receivedString):
        print(receivedString)
        return
```

output
this is test

Comment: thanks chinmay, it works on mine too, now I have something to work through.  Thanks very much!